# Insert Line in Multiples Files

Tags: centos, cron, wordpress

I have a CentOS Server with 200 Wordpress sites and now I want to insert this line in every wp-config.php file:

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true)
```

I know there exists a "for ... do ... done" possibility, but really I never used this before and I don't want to break all the sites. Please, help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be something like this:

```
for i in /path/to/*/wp-config.php; do
    echo "define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true)" >>$i
done
```

**Be sure to make backup before doing this!**

Comment: Thank you so much, works great... BTW: just one correction to the community: change `echo "define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true)" >>$i` for `echo "define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);" >>$i ` and, in my case, I have a little trouble with CHMOD but with the same command with some modifications it works like a charm... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it for files only in your current directory:

```
for file in $(ls *.php); do echo "define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true)" >> $file; done
```

If you want to do it for all php files starting from your current directory:

```
for file in $(find . -type f -name "*.php"); do echo "define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true)" >> $file; done
```

Or probably you want to insert that line at the beginning of all the files, so you can do this:

```
sed -i '1s/^/define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true)\n/' *.php
```